# Recover Truncated MyISAM Tables

Tags: mysql

I need to recover a truncated MyISAM table, i've browsed for solution on the web and found that there is way by using binary log recovery if it's enabled. but in my case the binary log is off, so there is no binary log file created.

Is there another way to make it happen? I desperately need it..

Comment: _desperately need it_. What you _desperately_ need is early backup. Having said that, you can try using a file recover software to recover data files.

Comment: do you have the software name? like ApexSQL..

Comment: Just search file recover software. It should yield some good results.